# calling a not-yet-existing and an already-gone property

Tags: javascript, function

The following code:

```js
var person = {
name: "john doe",
printName: function () {console.log(persona.name); }
};
person.printName();
var persona = person;
persona.printName();
```

[EDIT: doesn't] work<strike>s fine, and prints `john doe` twice</strike>.

It will output once if we'll log `person.name`.

Why does the first printing doesn't work, and why it outputs twice when (in the second case) `person` doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will not work, here is the example of it:

```js
var person = {
name: "john doe",
printName: function () {console.log(persona.name); }
};
person.printName();
```

Regarding the second case - the variable `persona` is only a reference to your `person` variable. You didn't delete it (so it still exists).

Check here:

```js
var person = {
name: "john doe",
printName: function () {console.log(persona.name); }
};
var persona = person;
person.printName();
persona.printName();
```

Comment: Your'e right regarding the first one, it's weird, I checked it in chrome's console and it worked, and then it didn't. Regarding the second one, shouldn't `person` be garbage collected (well, maybe if we'll enter some major code-work after the definition of `persona`)?

Comment: No, it's only a reference. Note that if you will change `persona` it **will** affect `person` and visa versa.